# php: looping thru results from mysql query to increment counter (associative array)

Tags: php, mysql, loops, switch-statement, associative-array

I'm retrieving data from a MySQL db and creating reports from it. I need to get counts when certain conditions are met, and since db queries are rather expensive (and I will have a lot of traffic), I'm looping thru the results from a single query in order to increment a counter.

It seems like it's working (the counter is incrementing) and the results are somewhat close, but the counters are not correct.

At the moment, there are 411 records in the table, but I'm getting numbers like 934 from a `['total']` counter and 927 for `['males']`, and that definitely can't be right. However, I get 4 from `['females']`, which is correct…

I'm pretty sure it was working last night, but now it's not—I'm quite baffled. (there are still just 411 records)

```
$surveydata = mysql_query("SELECT `age`,`e_part`,`gender` FROM $db_surveydata;") or die(mysql_error());
$rowcount = mysql_num_rows($surveydata);
$age=array('18+'=>0,'<18'=>0,'total'=>0);
$e_part=array('yes'=>0,'no'=>0,'total'=>0);
$genders=array('male'=>0,'female'=>0,'trans'=>0,'don\'t know'=>0,'total'=>0);

while ($responses = mysql_fetch_assoc($surveydata)) {
    foreach ($responses as $response){
        switch ($response){
            case $responses['age']:
                if ($responses['age'] > 18) {$age['18+']++;$age['total']++;}
                // i tried putting the ['total'] incrementer in the if/else
                // just in case, but same result
                else {$age['<18']++;$age['total']++;}
                break;
            case $responses['e_part']:
                if ($responses['e_part']) {$e_part['yes']++;}
                else {$e_part['no']++;}
                $e_part['total']++;
                break;
            case $responses['gender']:
                switch ($responses['gender']){
                    case 1:$genders['male']++;break;
                    case 2:$genders['female']++;break;
                    case 3:$genders['trans']++;break;
                    case 9:$genders['don\'t know']++;break;
                    default:break;
                }
                $genders['total']++;
                break;
            default:break;
        } // end switch
    } //end for
} // end while
```

thanks!

Comment: Try to insert some debugging statements in your code, to narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the problem:

```
foreach ($responses as $response){
        switch ($response){
            case $responses['age']:
```

switch $responses looks for match

```
foreach ($responses as $k=>$v){
    switch ($k){
        case 'age':
            if ($v > 18) ....
```

Comment: ahh! genius (and so much cleaner). Thanks!!

Comment: 'Cleaner'?  I'd argue that having `$v` be an age, an e_part, or a gender -- all in the same loop -- is pretty freaking messy.  :P  That said, it does solve the issue with the broken foreach.

Comment: it's not a suggestion, just an error fix. i wouldn't iterate over $response since all cases are treated differently (hence it won't save up code).

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_fetch_assoc()` retrieves a single row from the table. You then loop over that row, processing each individual field. Then the long set of `if()` checks to determine which field you're on. That entire structure could be changed to:

```
while($response = mysql_fetch_assoc($surveydata)) {
    if ($responses['age'] > 18) {
        $age['18+']++;
    } else {
        $age['<18']++;
    $age['total']++;}

    if ($responses['e_part']) {
        $e_part['yes']++;
    } else {
        $e_part['no']++;
    }
    $e_part['total']++;

    switch ($responses['gender']){
        case 1:$genders['male']++;break;
        case 2:$genders['female']++;break;
        case 3:$genders['trans']++;break;
        case 9:$genders['don\'t know']++;break;
        default:break;
    }
    $genders['total']++;
}
```

Comment: Hi Marc, the placement of the `['total']`s looks troublesome: won't they all increment every loop? Also, I try to avoid series of if-statements as I've had trouble with them not/activating inappropriately when there are "too many" (it's entirely possible the fault is mine, but nonetheless I try to avoid doing it).

Comment: If they're activating when they shouldn't, or vice versa, the problem is almost certainly a misunderstanding of the condition and/or the values you're testing.  `switch` looks plain odd when it's done when it doesn't have to be.  Which is to say, whenever `if` and/or `else` would be more appropriate.

Comment: Your query retrieves those age/e_part/gender fields for EVERY row. As such, the individual counts for age total/e_part total/gender_total would just equal the number of rows retrieved. If your allow questions to NOT be answered and want to count only filled-in answers, you'd have to do an `if ($response['age'] !== '') { $age['total']++; }` type thing.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for the `switch ($response)`; you can't really switch on an array like that.  And even if you could, the 'values' you get wouldn't make any sense -- i'm thinking if it works at all, the value you're switching on would be either 'Array' or the length of the array.  (I forget how PHP handles arrays-as-scalars.)

You'll want something like this...

```
$total = 0;
while ($response = mysql_fetch_assoc($surveydata))
{
    if (isset($response['age']))
    {
        ++$age[($response['age'] < 18) ? '<18' : '18+'];
        ++$age['total'];
    }
    if (isset($response['e_part']))
    {
        ++$e_part[($responses['e_part']) ? 'yes' : 'no'];
        ++$e_part['total'];
    }
    if (isset($response['gender']))
    {
        switch ($response['gender'])
        {
             case 1: ++$genders['male']; break;
             case 2: ++$genders['female']; break;
             case 3: ++$genders['trans']; break;
             case 9: ++$genders["don't know"]; break;
        }
        ++$genders['total'];
    }
    ++$total;
}
```

The benefit of the `if (isset(...))` is that if 'age', 'e_part', or 'gender' is null, the corresponding code to count it won't get activated.  It does about the same thing as your code, minus the embarrassing loop -- and minus the counting of the field even though it is null, because every row will have the same fields.